# PHP conditional array

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

I have a doubt about conditional array in php.
Here is my code;

```
foreach($orders as $order) {
    array_push($list, array($order['status'],$order['paid'],$order['name'],$order['email']));
}
```

Now i got the value of `$order['status']` is partial, and the  value of `$order['paid']` is yes. But what i m need is, if `$order['status']` is partial means, `$order['paid']` is empty.

I want to put condition before foreach loop. I dont know what is the best way.

Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: put it inside a variable first, then use a ternary. sample: `$paid = ($order['status'] == 'partial mean') ? null : $order['paid'];`, then assign `$paid` inside the `array_push()`

Comment: Can you explain more about what you're asking? I am failing to understand it

Comment: Are 'partial', 'yes', 'partial mean' and 'empty' supposed to be strings?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ternary operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) or simple if statement.

Ternary operator:

```
foreach($orders as $order) {
    array_push($list, array($order['status'], (($order['status']=='partial') ? $order['paid'] : null), $order['name'], $order['email']));
}
```

If statement:

```
foreach($orders as $order) {
    if ($order['status']=='partial') {
        array_push($list, array($order['status'],$order['paid'],$order['name'],$order['email']));
    } else {
        array_push($list, array($order['status'],null,$order['name'],$order['email']));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, and i have one doubt, Now i m using ternary operator, if not partial means, I get the value of $ordre['paid'].Can you help me?.

Comment: verify the condition: $order['status']=='partial' , is it right? Is 'partial means' a literal? If so, change it to $order['status']=='partial means'

Comment: Not like that, Means is just a word. I want, if $order['status']= 'partial', $order['paid']='null'. and  i want to need else condition within this code.. Did you get my question? Thank you.

Comment: Than replace (($order['status']=='partial') ? $order['paid'] : null) with (($order['status']=='partial') ? null : $order['paid'])
Please, make sure to familiarize with the description of ternary operator and its meaning, described here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary